# How do I use jQuery to change the value of a css selector value?

Tags: jquery, css

This is what I have:

```
<div class="class1 class2" style="background-image: url(https://background-image.jpg);"></div>
```

I want to use JQuery to target the two classes and change the value of the background image from https to http.  How can I do that?

I know I can do `.css` to append a value but I am not sure how I can change just the http value.  Is this possible?

Comment: To start with...don't use inline CSS.

Comment: this looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var bg = $('.class1.class2').css('background-image');
 $('.class1.class2').css('background-image',bg.replace('https','http'));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/12/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('.class1.class2').css('background-image',
function(_,val){ return val.replace('https','http');});
```